# Why can I not side-load a developer web add-in in Excel (works fine on other machines)?

Tags: excel, office365, add-in, office-addins, excel-web-addins

My team is developing an Office web add-in for Excel built in vanilla Javascript. To test and debug our project, we have been side-loading the add-in as per the usual steps.

Which are:

1. Navigate to `/Users/USERNAME/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Documents/wef`
2. Copy and paste `manifest.xml` file in above directory
3. Open Excel, click the insert tab, click My Add-Ins dropdown, then select the add-in described by the `manifest.xml` (which is under Developer Add-Ins)

This process works smoothly for everyone on the team except for one person. For that one person, after they have completed the steps, they see no Developer Add-Ins section, and no options to load the add-in described by the manifest.

What could be causing this issue?

More Info:
Problematic team member:

[image]

Non-problematic team members:

[image]

Comment: Is Group Policy or Office 365 management set to disable macros and developer tools for some users?

Comment: You don't need to post full-resolution screenshots of the About Excel pages - just posting the version numbers is sufficient. You've also inadvertently posted your Ontario University e-mail address.

Comment: Definitely wasn't worth the time to figure out which information was important, and wasn't happy about the resolution of the photos, but was also not going to spend time reducing the size. I figured both of these examples were not going to lower the quality of the question. Also, I spent the time to block out my Device ID, so obviously I made a conscious decision to leave my unused email. Appreciate the tips. Not sure what your first question is asking.

Comment: In Office 365, your organisation's administrator can block/prevent users from using developer-tools. Your screenshot shows that the affected computer is using Office 365 instead of a self-managed Office 2016 install, so I speculate that might be the reason.